# MAC - XAMPP 2019 Encontrar HTDOCS por comando para instalar Laravel

Tags: laravel, xampp

¿Dónde se encuentra HTDOCS con la nueva versión de XAMPP en mac?
Si antes en el directorio Aplicaciones teníamos el directorio XAMPP, y dentro del mismo HTDOCS, ahora no es igual.
¿Dónde está HTDOCS para poder instalar Laravel?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El directorio se encuentra en:

**/Users/[usuario]/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs**

*Observaciones: [usuario] será diferente en cada MAC. según configuración.*

Una vez en el se puede ejecutar el comando de instalación de Laravel:
"composer create-project laravel/laravel nombreproyecto"

Un saludo.